# How to configure macOS Server 5.11 for CI with XCode?

Tags: macos, xcode, osx-server

I have a question. I bought macOS Server from the App Store. I want to achieve this basically:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/
However, when I open Server, then on the left it is supposed to show XCode under Services, but it isn't.
I have posed my main question here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/1060038/how-to-let-osx-server-show-xcode-as-a-service
This is the main problem, but there seem to be a number of subproblems:

1. How to configure my router? (which ports should be forwarded?)
2. In XCode I enabled the Server under XCode > XCode Server ... (with the slider at the top right). I created the extra non-admin account on my Mac and permitted "node" through the firewall. Do I need to add a (non-guest) Server Account under Accounts in XCode?
3. In XCode, clicking Product > Create Bot ..., gives an alert: "Creating a bot requires that the project be under source control that is accessible by the server." Note: I put this project in the additional XCode Server logged in user account's shared folder, so I don't know why it wouldn't have access to it? What else/what is the default or best location for repo's and how can I set the location?
4. In macOS Server itself, how do I configure it? Under Julius's iMac Pro > Settings, ticking '[] Secure shell connections (SSH)' works, when I forward port 22 on the router and allow SSH in the macOS app firewall: I can SSH in over the internet (using my external IP). I haven't ticked the other two boxes. Under Julius's's iMac Pro > Overview the button Reachability Details... goves No available services (again, this is the main problem I think). I set Julius's's iMac Pro > Access to fairly restricted settings (only me, only this Mac), here it says: "macOS Application Firewall is enabled. Network access may be affected." However, I don't know how it may be affected, I can't add XCode here.

Comment: **so many questions**... and then one has to read all the links, too. Apart from the fact that I dont know enough to help you out, I doubt that anyone will be able to answer all that. Please have a look at the tour: https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour. Usually one question per question post is the way to go here...

Answer (score 1):

The article you linked is out of date. Xcode Server is now integrated directly into Xcode and OS X Server (now "macOS Server") is no longer required.

Here's an up-to-date tutorial on getting started with Xcode Server:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/12258400-xcode-server-for-ios-getting-started

I don't think you want to expose your Xcode Server to the internet, so you best use a VPN.

Comment: Thank you. The tutorial goes further and I get the git repo, but it is also superficial, for example when noting the provisioning service. XCode server now includes stuff like Nodejs, Redis, NGINX, but how to use them? For example, for automated testing? Is MacOS server now useless? I still don't get any services other than provisioning.

Comment: @JuliusBaer Yes, macOS Server is useless for your use-case. The technologies you listed (Node.js, Redis etc.) are just parts of Xcode server, not something you work with directly. All Xcode Server does is providing automated building of your Xcode project.